# javascript function to find the second largest element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am completing the hackerrank's 10 days of javascript challenge. The question:

> write a function to take an array as an argument and then return the second largest element in the array.

I have written the code but my code is returning the largest element and not the second largest as asked.

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    // Complete the function
    var largest=nums[0];
    for(let i=1;i<nums.length;++i)
    {
        if(nums[i]>largest)
        largest=nums[i];
    }
    var large=nums[0];
    for(let j=1;j<nums.length;++j)
    {
        if(large<nums[j]&&large<largest)
        large=nums[j];
    }
    return large;
}
```

When input array `nums={2,3,6,6,5}` the result is coming `6` while expected output is 5.  Please help and point out the errors in the function code below.

Comment: But why this complex logic when you can do it in just 2 lines? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62058479/13531204

Comment: you are right, actually i used the above way so i accepted that answer. Although both are great ways... thanks for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one minor change:

Use `nums[j]<largest` instead of `large<largest` in the second for loop

```js
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    // Complete the function
    var largest=nums[0];
    for(let i=1;i<nums.length;++i)
    {
        if(nums[i]>largest)
        largest=nums[i];
    }
    var large;
    
    //To ensure that the selected number is not the largest
    for(let j=0;j<nums.length;++j)
    {
        if (nums[j] !== largest){
            large = nums[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    for(let j=1;j<nums.length;++j)
    {
        if(large<nums[j]&&nums[j]!=largest)
            large=nums[j];
        else
            
        console.log(large)
    }
    return large;
}

var secondLargest = getSecondLargest([6,3,6,6,5]);
console.log("Second largest number", secondLargest);
```

Comment: @Dhruv Bansal checkout this answer

Comment: @Dhruv Bansal updated the answer as per this use case where first number is the largest number

Answer (score 2):

- should not initialize `large` with first value `var large=nums[0];` because it may appear the biggest value and won't work
- should use `nums[j]<largest instead of large<largest` as mentioned above
- I think don't need second loop as all checks can be done in first loop, and you can assign prev largest to large whenever you change it:

```js
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  var largest = nums[0];
  var large;
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; ++i) {
    if (nums[i] > largest) {
        large = largest;
        largest = nums[i];
    } else if (nums[i] > large || typeof large === 'undefined') {
        large = nums[i]
    }
  }
  return large;
}
console.log(getSecondLargest([5,1-2,3]))
console.log(getSecondLargest([-5,1,-2,3]))
```

Comment: Input 2 3 6 6 4 it will through wrong result

Answer (score 2):

**GET SECOND LARGEST**

**first**, I create new array with unique values.

**`let arr = [...new Set(nums)];`**

**second**, sort value using built-in function `.sort()`.

note : by default `.sort()` always sorts asciibetically, but for some testcase, it doesn't work. So, I put `(a, b) => { return a - b }` to make sure it will work properly.

**`arr = arr.sort((a, b) => { return a -b });`**

**third**, get the value from `arr`

**`let result = arr[arr.length - 2] || arr[0];`**

**finally**, return the result

**`return result`**

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  let arr = [...new Set(nums)];

  //Javascript's array member method .sort( always sorts asciibetically.
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => { return a - b });
  let result = arr[arr.length - 2] || arr[0];
  return result
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works... have you tested it yourself? try `[1, 2, 5]`. Please provide an explanation

Comment: thanks @MZ,

STEPS :
1. `let arr` create new array with unique value
2. after get all uniques, array will be sorting the value
3. `let result` getting value. If `arr[arr.length - 2]` is undefined, result equals to `arr[0]`
4. `return` it as the result

Comment: @Irwan You should add that explanation to the answer itself, rather than down here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using library functions like @ifaruki suggests, this line

`if(large<nums[j]&&large<largest)`

should read

`if (large<nums[j] && nums[j] < largest)`

Sorting and picking the second or second-to-last value fails when there are duplicates of the highest value in the input array.

Answer (score 0):

> Another easiest logic is to remove duplicates from the array and sort.

```js
let givenArray = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5];
let uniqueArray = [...new Set(givenArray)];

console.log("The second largets element is", uniqueArray.sort()[uniqueArray.length - 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you had your question answered, just thought I would provide my solution for any future users looking into this.

You can use reduce to go through the array while remembering the two largest numbers so far.

You just make a simple reduction function:

```
function twoMax(two_max, candidate)
{
    if (candidate > two_max[0]) return [candidate,two_max[0]];
    else if (candidate > two_max[1]) return [two_max[0],candidate];
    else return two_max;
}
```

And then you use it for example like this:

```
let my_array = [0,1,5,7,0,8,12];
let two_largest = my_array.reduce(twoMax,[-Infinity,-Infinity]);
let second_largest = two_largest[1];
```

This solution doesn't require sorting and goes through the array only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using **sort method. I think here's the easiest logic to do that, which will also work in arrays where there's *duplicates* of largest integer exists.

```js
function getSecondLargest(arr) {
  const largest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (largest === arr[i]) {
      arr[i] = -Infinity;
    }
  }
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}
console.log(getSecondLargest([5, 7, 11, 11, 11])); //7
```

Answer (score 0):

In one loop you can do it

```js
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    // Complete the function
    let fl = 0; // First Large
    let sl = 0; // Second Large
    for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        if(fl < nums[i]){
            sl = fl;//3
            fl = nums[i];//6
        } else if ((sl < nums[i]) && (fl != nums[i])) {
            sl = nums[i]
        }
    }
    return sl;
}

console.log(getSecondLargest([5,1-2,3]))
console.log(getSecondLargest([-5,1,-2,3]))
console.log(getSecondLargest([2,3,6,6,5]))
```